# How to find minimum values in a column in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

If I have a table like this:

```
id   name   value
1    abc      1
2    def      4
3    ghi      1
4    jkl      2
```

How can I select a new table that still has `id, name, value` but only the ones with a minimum value.

In this example I need this table back:

```
1  abc 1
3  ghi 1
```

Comment: What's your DBMS? If it supports `ROW_NUMBER` it's simple.

Comment: @dnoeth I'm using postgresql

Comment: Check @Lamak's answer, this is even simpler.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finding those values is pretty straightforward:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE value = (SELECT MIN(Value) FROM YourTable);
```

As for the right syntax for putting those rows in another table, that will depend on the database engine that you are using.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to @Lamak's solution could be to use the `rank` window function. Depending on the exact scenario, it may perform quite better:

```
SELECT id, name, value
FROM   (SELECT id, name, value, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY value ASC) AS rk
        FROM   mytable) t
WHERE  rk = 1
```

Comment: I like this as well as you could specify a specific rank 2, 3, 4, etc to get a specific rank outside of min or max.

Comment: @xQbert It is more general solution but raises the scan and caching of the whole table.

Answer (score 1):

not sure exactly if this is what you're trying to do, but I think this would work:

```
    --creating #temp1 to recreate your table/example
     CREATE TABLE #TEMP1
    (id      INT       NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
     name    CHAR(3)   NOT NULL,
     value   INT       NOT NULL)


    INSERT INTO #TEMP1
    VALUES 
    (1,'abc',1), 
    (2,'def',4), 
    (3,'ghi',1), 
    (4,'jkl',2)

    -verify correct

    SELECT * FROM #temp1

    --populate new table with min value from table 1

    SELECT *
    INTO #TEMP2
    FROM #TEMP1
    WHERE value = (SELECT MIN(value) 
                   FROM #TEMP1)

    SELECT * FROM #TEMP2
```